# badge position for nodes

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape-web

I'm trying to add badges to my cytoscape.js nodes. Badges are HTML elements. I'm using [bootstrap badges](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/badge/#pill-badges)

Here are elements with badges. (the colors of the badges are irrelevant)
[image]

When I zoom out, the position of the badges is not set correctly. They go **down**  and **right** a bit. WHY IS THAT?

[image: badges goes down a bit]

Here is my code to set the positions. I but badges to to top left of the node. But I remove width of the HTML element to make it look like inside the node

```
let z1 = cy.zoom() / 2; // badges look too big with normal size so I downscale them
// e is cytoscape.js element, a node
const p = e.renderedPosition();
const eW = e.renderedWidth() / 2;
const eH = e.renderedHeight() / 2;
// div is an HTML element which is the badge
const w = div.clientWidth;
div.style.transform = `translate(${p.x + eW - w * z1}px, ${p.y - eH}px) scale(${z1})`;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem stems from CSS `scale`. When I scale the element, the center point of the element remains invariant. The below sample shows What I mean

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
}
span {
  font-size: 64px;
}

.s1 {
  transform: scale(1);
  background: red;
}

.s2 {
  transform: scale(0.5);
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="s1"><span>00</span></div>
<div class="s2"><span>00</span></div>
```

So I have to consider the center point of the `div`. Below code does that

```
let z1 = this._g.cy.zoom() / 2;
const bb = e.renderedBoundingBox({ includeLabels: false, includeOverlays: false });
const w = div.clientWidth;
const h = div.clientHeight;
const deltaW4Scale = (1 - z1) * w / 2;
const deltaH4Scale = (1 - z1) * h / 2;
div.style.transform = `translate(${bb.x2 - deltaW4Scale - w * z1}px, ${bb.y1 - deltaH4Scale}px) scale(${z1})`;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would personally prefer a solution using cytoscape.js resources/extensions, namely the popper.js extension.

As far as I understand your problem, you add bootstrap elements to cytoscape.js in some way (you didn't specify this, so I have to guess).

Nomrally, a sticky popper div does the trick for this problem:

```js
var cy = (window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById("cy"),

  style: [{
      selector: "node",
      css: {
        content: "data(id)",
        "text-valign": "center",
        "text-halign": "center",
        height: "60px",
        width: "160px",
        shape: "round-rectangle"
      }
    },
    {
      selector: "edge",
      css: {
        "target-arrow-shape": "triangle"
      }
    }
  ],

  elements: {
    nodes: [{
        data: {
          id: "n0"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n1"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n2"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n3"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n4"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n5"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n6"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n7"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n8"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n9"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n10"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n11"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n12"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n13"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n14"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n15"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n16"
        }
      }
    ],
    edges: [{
        data: {
          source: "n0",
          target: "n1"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n1",
          target: "n2"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n1",
          target: "n3"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n4",
          target: "n5"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n4",
          target: "n6"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n6",
          target: "n7"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n6",
          target: "n8"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n8",
          target: "n9"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n8",
          target: "n10"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n11",
          target: "n12"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n12",
          target: "n13"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n13",
          target: "n14"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n13",
          target: "n15"
        }
      }
    ]
  },

  layout: {
    name: "dagre",
    padding: 5,
    rankSep: 100
  }
}));

var makeTippy = function(node, text) {
  var ref = node.popperRef();
  var dummyDomEle = document.createElement("div");

  var tip = tippy(dummyDomEle, {
    onCreate: function(instance) {
      instance.popperInstance.reference = ref;
    },
    lazy: false, // mandatory
    trigger: "manual", // mandatory

    // dom element inside the tippy:
    content: function() {
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.innerHTML = text;
      return div;
    },

    // your own preferences:
    arrow: false,
    placement: 'top-end',
    hideOnClick: false,
    multiple: true,
    sticky: true
  });

  return tip;
};

cy.ready(function() {
  cy.zoom(0.75);
  cy.center();
  cy.ready(function() {
    let nodes = cy.nodes();
    nodes.each(function(node) {
      let tippy = makeTippy(node, node.id());
      tippy.show();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#cy {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.tippy-popper {
  transition: none !important;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dagre@0.7.4/dist/dagre.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cytoscape-dagre@2.1.0/cytoscape-dagre.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cytoscape-popper@1.0.6/cytoscape-popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@5.1.3/dist/tippy-bundle.iife.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@5.1.3/dist/tippy.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

This snippet cuts some of the container off, so try this in your application for better results and take a look at the extensions used [here](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-popper)

Comment: I tried to use that extension. But I found positioning with that extension more challenging because that extension uses another extension called https://popper.js.org/ and it does not give an option to put the labels at the center. Also, the extension uses an old version of popper.js

Comment: You can customize every popper element with css, so positioning is not an issue.